# How to upload an entire folder on the client and recover its structure on a java web server?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, directory

Is there a way to upload an entire folder with all its subdirectories and files from a client using a POST request from javascript and recover the folder structure on a java web server?
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest that you compress it first, it would make your task way easier.
Compress it -> Send it -> receive it -> Decompress it -> Tada you have the same structure.

Comment: I cannot use system utilities for that, I can only rely on the browser, and I am not sure the browser can handle that especially that I have large files to be compressed (>1GB) and then uploaded.